# Error during unpickling in python. AttributeError: 'Airthematic' object has no attribute '__addition'

Tags: python, pickle

Below is the sample code, I pickled it successfully but unpickling gives an error. Anyone knows the cause or solution will much be appreciated.

sample.py

```
import pandas as pd

class Airthematic(object):
    
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol_ = symbol
        self.__x = None
        self.__y = None
        self.__result = None
        self.__function_mapping = {
            "+": self.__addition,
            "-": self.__subtraction,
            "*": self.__multiplication
        }
        
    def calculate(self, x, y):
        
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        self.__result = self.__function_mapping[self.symbol_]()
    
    def __addition(self):
        return self.__x+self.__y
    
    def __subtraction(self):
        return self.__x-self.__y
    
    def __multiplication(self):
        return self.__x*self.__y

    @property
    def first_number_(self):
        return self.__x

    @property
    def second_number_(self):
        return self.__y

    @property
    def result_(self):
        return self.__result
```

Here is the code in juypter

```
from sample import Airthematic
a = Airthematic("+")
a.calculate(5, 6)
pd.to_pickle(a, "../output/sample.pickle") # Successful
aa = pd.read_pickle("../output/sample.pickle") # Giving error
```

AttributeError: 'Airthematic' object has no attribute '__addition'

Somehow the dict which contains function mapping giving an error.

Comment: Please read up on https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle specifically the "What can you pickle" part

Comment: Methods and attributes that begin with a double underscore `__` have their names "mangled", they end up actually being named "_ClassName__name". If you rename those methods so that begin with a single underscore you may have more luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as @IainShelvington explained, private attributes and function names are different. So after I pickled, I opened the file in notepad and observed it. I found that private attribute names are saved as _Airthematic__x, _Airthematic__y, and so on. But function names are not stored as that it is stored as __multiplication for attribute _Airthematic__function_mapping. Also, I noticed after reading docs shared by @ewong that function names are not saved in the pickle file. So when unpickling it will find attribute named __multiplication which is not present in the pickle file as the function name is not stored. So I found the solution, has to implement "__getstate__" and "__setstate__" functions. Below is the revised version which will work fine.

```
import pandas as pd

class Airthematic(object):
    
    def __init__(self, symbol):
        self.symbol_ = symbol
        self.__x = None
        self.__y = None
        self.__result = None
        self.__function_mapping = {
            "+": self.__addition,
            "-": self.__subtraction,
            "*": self.__multiplication
        }


    def __getstate__(self):

        state = self.__dict__.copy()

        # Remove the unpicklable entries.
        del state["_" + str(self.__class__.__name__) + '__function_mapping']
        return state


    def __setstate__(self, state):
        # Restore instance attributes (i.e., function_mapping).
        self.__dict__.update(state)
        self.__function_mapping = {
            "+": self.__addition,
            "-": self.__subtraction,
            "*": self.__multiplication
        }

        
    def calculate(self, x, y):
        
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
        self.__result = self.__function_mapping[self.symbol_]()
    
    def __addition(self):
        return self.__x+self.__y
    
    def __subtraction(self):
        return self.__x-self.__y
    
    def __multiplication(self):
        return self.__x*self.__y

    @property
    def first_number_(self):
        return self.__x

    @property
    def second_number_(self):
        return self.__y

    @property
    def result_(self):
        return self.__result
```